# Why use devnull with subprocess.check_output in python2?

Tags: c++, subprocess, pipe, cluster-computing, python-2.x

I have inherited a complicated (to me) toolbox from a PhD student before me and it uses python2 instead of 3 since it's older. The main file is in python2 and uses lots of modules and user-made scripts within it. A key one involves a python2 script running a C++ program which then returns a long string of data for the python2 script to interpret and pass back to the main script. This was working fine until I had to move from the computing cluster this code was written on to the newer cluster, going from torque to slurm.

In addition I did upgrade part of the toolbox, specifically the programs called by the  C++ program - but the program calls these and runs them correctly and literally just returns numbers calculated through them back to the python script so I do not believe that upgrade is the problem.

In the original code python2 runs the C++ code like so:

```
def main(template_file, pars, vars):
    """Run requested command and return list of result values."""

    global arguments, timeout, timelimit, formula_eval, data_fields_code

    with open(os.devnull) as devnull, timelimit(timeout):
        output = subprocess.check_output(
            arguments + ([template_file] if template_file else []),
            stdin=devnull,
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
        )
    
    # group 0 is the full number match
    # make sure it stays that way when changing number_pattern!
    all_numbers = [float(x[0]) for x in re.findall(number_pattern, output)]
```

`arguments` is python2 bytecode, it contains the command to run the C++ as well as a point in some space (like (x, y, z) all as decimals). As you can see the template file is not required, its just an alternate way of inputting data to the system, on the C++ end it looks like so;

```
int       yt_in;  // - Type
double    Z7_in;  // - Z7
double    mH_in;  // - mH
double   mHc_in;  // - mHc
double    mA_in;  // - mA
double   cba_in;  // - cos(b-a)
double    tb_in;  // - tan(b)

if     ( argc == 2 )   // - filename as input
{
    ifstream file( argv[1]);
    //  file.open( fname.c_str(), ios::in);
    file >> yt_in;
    file >> Z7_in;
    file >> mH_in;
    file >> mHc_in;
    file >> mA_in;
    file >> cba_in;
    file >> tb_in;
    file.close();
}

else if ( argc == 8 )   // - parameters as input
{
     yt_in      = (int)   atoi(argv[1]);
     Z7_in      = (double)atof(argv[2]);
     mH_in      = (double)atof(argv[3]);
     mHc_in     = (double)atof(argv[4]);
     mA_in      = (double)atof(argv[5]);
     cba_in     = (double)atof(argv[6]);
     tb_in      = (double)atof(argv[7]);
}
```

So that if a template is given the first option is used, if not then the bytecode already has the variables in it to directly (the main python2 file generates a point by default so it is easily passed along, I am not really sure why there are two different ways of doing this, I have only ever used it where points are generated in the main file. I would also like to mention that there is not really any documentation for this for me to refer to).

Below is the original method of output for the C++ file;

```
std::cout

// -- Input
<< Z7_in  << " "                    // 1
<< mH_in  << " "                   // 2

....

<< k_huu  << " "                    // 75
<< k_hdd  <<                        // 76

    std::endl;

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Finished passing variables over!");
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
```

When I try using the original method for calling the C++ code the program just gets stuck and loops on the steps beforehand (it is designed to loop, selecting a point and processing it then selecting another etc, but it does not run the C++ code on the points).

I tried altering the code so that instead of streaming the data from the c++ code it would write it to a file named with a randomised string. Then just pass this string to cout for the python2 script to receive and use to open the file and read in the data. The file gets created correctly by the C++ initially, I can find and open it myself and see that it is working. The file name seems to be passed back to the python correctly also as I can get it to print out the string and the type of the output, which is string as expected.

But then instead of carrying on with the python2 script as expected it starts running the c++ again on the *same point* instead of going back to the main python script and generating a new one. It does this four times for some reason, then gives up. My changed python2 code is below;

```
def main(template_file, pars, vars):
    """Run requested command and return list of result values."""
    print '### --- Inside SimpleProcessor.main --- '
    print '                                        '
    global arguments, timeout, timelimit, formula_eval, data_fields_code

    print 'arguments', arguments
    print 'formula_eval', formula_eval
    print'data_fields_code', data_fields_code
    print 'template_file', template_file

    cwd = os.getcwd()
    print "current working dir is: " + str(cwd)
    output = subprocess.check_output(
            arguments + [template_file] if template_file else [])

    print output
    print "                      "
    print "The above is output from check_output"
    print "                      "
    print( "result type is: ", type(output))

    print "Current dir is: " + str(os.getcwd())
    path_to_file = str(output)
    print "the output file is: " + str(path_to_file)

    if os.path.isfile(path_to_file):
        print str(path_to_file) + " exists"
    else:
        print str(path_to_file) + " could not be located"
```

Sometimes it thinks the file exists, sometimes it doesn't while doing this weird looping. The file is present the whole time though, and it's actually using the same random string each time so it's always looking for the same file. I don't know how that's happening since the C++ generates the random string. I can only think that there's something wrong with the `subprocess.check_output` where it's taking in the same information multiple times. But the python doesn't even reach the same point before restarting the loop each time! Sometimes it gets as far as indicating it can/t find the datafile, sometimes it only gets as far as `print output`. I can't switch to python3 (unfortunately) as the main python script is python2 and as a PhD student I don't have the time needed to upgrade that.

Can anyone help me?

----------Edit-----------------
It turned out that a single line in a python file higher up in the chain had been deleted somehow (I ssh into the cluster and it drops every five minutes recently so I suspect something got written over accidentally). I don't fully understand how that line led to these weird affects, but thanks everyone for trying to help and also thank goodness for github backups!!

Comment: The answer to your title question + `stdin=devnull` is probably: It's to disconnect the script from the controlling tty. If the started subprocess for some reason tries to read something from `stdin`, it would (without `stdin=devnull`) stop there and wait for the user to actually type something - or if a redirect is used, it would read from that.

Comment: I see. But then it still will run the C++ code fully without the devnull part, so presumably it doesn't read from the tty? Sorry if I'm being slow, but what do you mean redirect? Why would devnull's absence mean it doesn't work?

Comment: Redirecting stdin means when you read from stdin (that's the C version, C++ calls it cin) you actually read from something other than the terminal keyboard. devnull is a fake file that pretends to be an empty file when you read it. Reading from devnull always fails (end of file). So if you redirect stdin from devnull then cin>> always fails

Comment: @user253751 `stdin` is certainly a part of `c++` too as documented by [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/std_streams)

Comment: @user253751 ah okay. Yeah that makes sense since this code is designed to run on a cluster for long periods of time without user interference. But if I want it to read what is being passed by the python why would I not just want to use subprocess.call or subprocess.check_output with a pipe instead? I always thought of devnull as a sort of  rubbish bin/unpredictable stream?

Comment: @Ciara when writing to devnull, whatever data you write gets deleted, when reading it acts like an empty file. For unpredictable you might be thinking of /dev/urandom which returns random bytes when read.

Comment: @user253751 if it has consistent behaviour then why would it stop working after I moved clusters? I use conda to manage my python environment so the new one is literally a clone of the old one. It is a different version of C++ as the new cluster didn't have the old version I was using, could that cause issues?

Comment: @Ciara you will need to troubleshoot and find out what the problem is. I doubt that stdin=devnull is the problem. Do you know where the C++ code gets stuck? Can you run the C++ part by itself, without the Python part, but with the same arguments as if the Python part was calling it? Does it behave the same way when you do that?

Comment: @user253751 The C++ code doesn't get stuck. Using the devnull code it doesn't get run at all. The python code loops on the steps leading up to it. Using my new method, not involving devnull, the C++ code runs fully and creates the output that it should. Instead it's like the subprocess function in python is feeding everything output by the C++ multiple times and not continuing with the rest of the script. I'm sure the C++ only runs once because it generates a random string and uses this to create a new file with that name. The same string is shown for all repeats and just one file is created.

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, complete, reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Separately opening `os.devnull` seems like a _bona fide_ bug. Use the predefined contstant `subprocess.DEVNULL` which exists for precisely this purpose instead.

Comment: @user253751 its difficult given all the working parts. I will try to figure something out though.

Comment: @tripleee is that not a python3 thing? I tried it here and got the error 'module' object has no attribute DEVNULL

Comment: Oh, you're right. I somehow got the impression you were porting this to Python 3 but I guess not.

Comment: Your question had some apparent indentation errors; I tried to fix them, but obviously had to guess a bit - please review.

Comment: As an aside, there is no way the current working directory could change between the repeated calls to `os.getcwd()` so you could get away with calling it just once.

Comment: @tripleee I wish I could port it to python 3, it's too big and complicated and time is running out on my PhD (which is in physics not computer science or something), I just need it to run again so I have data! Also thank-you for fixing the indentation errors! I don't really need the os.getcwd() it was just part of me trying to figure out whats going on! I do have access to python 3 in that I'm using conda for my python enviroment, is it possible to import subprocess.run or something to python 2 like you can with other bits?

Comment: I don't think there's a backport of that, `subprocess.check_output` is the best you can get in 2.7.